# Is it possible to define different attributes for recursive classes in F#

Tags: f#, attributes

I want to declare two classes that are associated, therefore I am declaring them together linked by an 'and'. Each has different attributes but this code is not working ("Unexpected keyword 'and' in definition" error at keyword 'and'. How should I declare the attributes of the second class?

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type foo() =
  abstract member fun1 : foo -> foo2
[<Serializable>]
and foo2() = class
  member x.bar y = y
end
```

Answer (score 10):

It works for me. Did you do `open System`?

```
open System

[<AbstractClass>]
type foo() =
  abstract member fun1 : foo -> foo2
and [<Serializable>] foo2() = class
  member x.bar y = y
end
```

Edit:
Ah, it seems that the second attribute should be AFTER the `and`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I opened System and yes the solution is to place it **after** the `and`.

Ta!